# How can I change text color via keyboard shortcut in MS word 2010

Tags: ms-word, word-2010

While typing sentences I would like to change the text color at few places. To do so I have to do it manually by going to fonts pop section. Is there any way to create a keyboard shortcut so that I can change the text color of some word in sentence while I am typing?

Answer (score 43):

For Word 2010 and 2013, go to `File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Keyboard Shortcuts > All Commands (in left list) > Color: (in right list)` -- at this point, you type in the short cut (such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) and select the color (such as red). (This actually goes back to 2003 but I don't have that installed to provide the pathway.)

Comment: Much faster than the Alt + H solution!

Comment: This works for Word 2007 as well. Thanks; I've been looking for this for years!

Comment: In Word 2019 (or whichever version was released then, since this piece of shit program doesn't let me view the version from help) you can't assign ctrl+G, well you can, but the coloring doesn't work if you do.

Comment: For Word 2019, with @louis.com solution you can only use preset colors, if you want to color with active color, find TextFillEffectDefaultFont and use that.

Comment: You can add "Customize Ribbon"  to quick bar to facilitate the process of setting up shorcuts.

Comment: You lost me at "and select the color". I don't see anywhere to do that and the shortcut turns my text red, regardless of what keys I choose.

Answer (score 14):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, then type letters <kbd>FC</kbd>, then pick the color.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a macro, but it’s simpler to use styles. Define a character style that has the desired text color and assign a shortcut key to it, say <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. In order to be able to switch color using just the keyboard, define another character style, say “normal”, that has no special feature—just for use to get normal text after switching to your colored style, and assign another shortcut to it, say <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. Then you would just type text, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to switch to colored text, type that text, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to resume normal text color, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H(h)</kbd> and then you'll see the shortcuts on the toolbar, press <kbd>FC</kbd> to operate color menu and press <kbd>A</kbd>(Automatic) for black or browse through other colors using arrow keys.